# Learning Latin through Aeneid (or another text)

Tags: reference-request, aeneis

Could you recommend courses/textbooks for learning Latin via a text ?

More specifically: there are exist courses like [Reading Course in Homeric Greek](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1585101753) teaching one (Homeric) Greek through selected fragments of a real text, rather than through synthetic or simplified examples of the language, more suitable for the student's level.  There are also some text for learning Hebrew that take this approach (as well as multiple commentaries on the chapters of the Old Testament, guiding one through every passage, explaining the grammatical phenomena as they are encountered.) In both cases the courses prepare one to continue one's study of the text independently, rather than teaching language as a system first, and then separately teaching how to analyze a text.

Are there similar resources for Latin, e.g., via studying and analyzing *Aeneid*? In fact, I am pretty sure that such resources exists, so this is mostly a reference request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's [Latin Via Ovid](https://www.wsupress.wayne.edu/books/detail/latin-ovid) (2nd ed. 1982):

From the publisher's website:

> Using an introduction to mythology by the master storyteller Ovid himself, the authors have prepared a unique teaching tool designed to achieve proficiency at Latin in one year at the college level, two years at the high school or intermediate level. The volume provides students with imaginative, connected reading, beginning with introductory prose versions of Ovid's simple myth tales and progressing to the rich poetry of Ovidian Latin (with appropriate teaching aids) within forty lessons. The grammatical approach is traditional, but the central emphasis is on reading. In each chapter the reading appears first, followed by the vocabulary, the grammar, exercises, and etymology relating to the vocabulary. The exercises begin with a group of questions in Latin (based on the reading), to be answered in Latin. Each tale is preceded by a brief discussion in English of the story and its mythological significance. The myths retold by Ovid and the attractive format are conceived to impel the student into acquiring the skill to read the author in the original language.